# installing three packages at once fails: "pip install numpy pil aptus" but individually they work, why?

Tags: python, numpy, installation, virtualenv, pip

logs and more details are at: https://gist.github.com/2890621

```
stu@vervet ~ $ virtualenv --no-site-packages testingpip
New python executable in testingpip/bin/python
Installing distribute......................done.
stu@vervet ~ $ source testingpip/bin/activate
stu@vervet ~ $ which pip
/home/stu/testingpip/bin/pip
stu@vervet ~ $ which python
/home/stu/testingpip/bin/python
stu@vervet ~ $ pip --log=piplog.log install numpy pil aptus
Downloading/unpacking numpy
...
...
...
```

*ultimately the command fails because of the numpy dependency*

but doing:

```
stu@vervet ~ $ pip install numpy
stu@vervet ~ $ pip install pil
stu@vervet ~ $ pip install aptus
```

*works*

Comment: putting `numpy`, `pil` and `aptus` in a requirements.txt doesn't work either,  `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails just the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [this line](https://bitbucket.org/ned/aptus/src/c053d5f7a949/setup.py#cl-15) in the Aptus setup.py file.

You should report that as a bug with Aptus. If Aptus depends on numpy, it should add it to its list of dependencies, not throw an exception during installation.

Aptus should be patched to something like this:

```
install_requires = []

try: import numpy
except ImportError: install_requires.append('numpy')

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into Aptus' code. I'm aware Aptus depends on numpy, but shouldn't numpy be installed *already* when I `pip install numpy pil aptus`?

Comment: No, pip does not necessarily install things in order.

Comment: But if you look at the log: https://gist.github.com/2890621, you can see it is installing them in the right order, or atleast attempts to... am I missing something?

Comment: It downloads and compiles each package first, then installs them all after everything finishes, so even though numpy has been built, it's not available in the python runtime yet.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks.  But how do large `requirements.txt` files which contain many dependencies work then?  Wouldn't this be a common problem?

Comment: Yes, because pip will do things properly when the requirement is specified - e.g. if it knows that aptus depends on numpy, it will install numpy first